# How to separate text file data into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a text file which contains questions and answers to a trivia game, each anwser is seperated from its question with a tab ("\t") and each question/anwser combination is on its own line. Like this:

```
In which movie does Michael J. Fox play a time-travelling teenager?    Back to the Future
In 'Old School', what song does Frank try and sing at Blue's funeral.  Dust In The Wind
What hiphop heroes joined forces with Aerosmith for a new version of Walk This Way?    Run DMC
What singer's February 6 birthday is a national holiday in Jamaica?    Bob Marley
What year did Steven Page leave BNL?   2009
What is a group of turtles known as?   A pod
```

I am trying to create an array where I can separate questions and answers, but it keeps giving me an array with a size of 2 and the output is a group of all the questions or a group of all the answers and i cant seem to separate them any further. Here is what I have so far:

```
$fileHandler = fopen('triviaQuestions.txt', 'r');

if ($fileHandler) {
    while (($line = fgets($fileHandler)) != false) {
        $line = explode("\t", $line);

        echo $line[0];
    }
    fclose($fileHandler);
}
```

This is the output I get from that:

```
In which movie does Michael J. Fox play a time-travelling teenager?In 'Old School', what song does Frank try and sing at Blue's funeral.What hiphop heroes joined forces with Aerosmith for a new version of Walk This Way?What singer's February 6 birthday is a national holiday in Jamaica?What year did Steven Page leave BNL?What is a group of turtles known as?
```

As you can see it just groups all the questions as $line[0] rather than separate them from each other. It does the same thing to the answers when I try $line[1].

Comment: Well you have to seperate them with something when you echo them, for example `echo $line[0] . '<br>';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes but my goal is not to simply have them on different lines, I need to be able to call each specific piece by itself to create the trivia game and display one question at a time.

Comment: Then put the questions and answers in 2 seperate arrays like  `$ques = $line[0]; $ans[] = $line[1];`

Comment: @RiggsFolly so now if I try something like 'echo $ques[5];' what it does is it tries to output it 6 times (once for every line in the text file) but on the first 5 times it says "Undefined offset: 5" and on the 6th one it outputs the correct question. When i try it with 'echo $ques[4]' it does the same thing except the 5th and 6th output become the ques[4] output.

Comment: We do not have a clear expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php

$fileHandler = fopen('triviaQuestions.txt', 'r');

if ($fileHandler) {

    $ques = [];
    $ans = [];

    while (($line = fgets($fileHandler)) !== false) {

        $line = explode("   ", $line);

        // Not each anwser is seperated from its question with a tab.
        // For example:
        // In 'Old School', what song does Frank try and sing at Blue's funeral.  Dust In The Wind
        if (!isset($line[1])) {
            $line = explode("  ", $line[0]);
        }

        $ques[] = $line[0];
        $ans[] = $line[1];

    }

    $counter = 0;
    $str = "";

    foreach ($ques as $que) {

        $answer = $ans[$counter];
        $counter += 1;

        $str .= "Q: " . $que;
        $str .= "<br />";
        $str .= "A: " . $answer;
        $str .= "<br />";
        $str .= "<hr />";

    }

    echo $str;
    fclose($fileHandler);

}
```